# The path of APPDIR in RemoveExistingProducts action is wrong and the sequence failed with error 1606

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer

I use Advanced Installer to create an update package for my application.

At the Installation Execution Stage, I have these sequence :

[image]

1. I have PreserveInstallType_1
2. Searches which search some XML properties in config file.
3. Custom actions : SetPropertyAPPDIR_1, SetPropertyAPPDATA_1, SetPropertyDOCS_1. It set the properties APPDIR, APPDATA and an other DOCS with the good path.
4. Next, we can see Path Resolution sequence.
5. Next it's the Preparing sequence. In this sequence we have RemoveExistingProducts and I think it's this action which failed.

Indeed, I look the logs file and I can see the good path in APPDIR and TARGETDIR just before RemoveExistingProducts. There are a path like C:\Program Files (x86)...
But in the RemoveExistingProducts a SET_APPDIR is done and a wrong value is set (it's the ProductName not a path).

I don't know where this value come from and i check my path just before this sequence.

Why in RemoveExistingProducts the SET_APPDIR action doesn't give the good path to APPDIR ?

There is a way to set the APPDIR with custom action or other in this action ?

Thank you for your help, currently i'm blocked.

Answer (score 0):

APPDIR is an Advanced Installer proprietary property and this should be automatically handled by the setup package you built with their tool. I would recommend you to contact Advanced Installer support team or to post your question on their [community forums](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/).

Comment: Yes I did that and they solved my issue. Thank you.